# How to run a docker container for ruby on rails without root user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a RoR project without root user on docker. I'm using the official ruby image and when I execute `bundle install` with a non root user everything goes okay, but when I run `rails s -b '0.0.0.0'` or `bundle exec rails s -b '0.0.0.0'` I get this error:

> /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:37:in `fetch': Permission denied - bs_fetch:atomic_write_cache_file:open (Errno::EACCES)

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

COPY controleGarrafao/ /home/docker/controleGarrafao

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install sudo
WORKDIR /home/docker/controleGarrafao
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/bundle

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | \
    chpasswd

RUN echo "docker ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | \ 
    tee -a /etc/sudoers

RUN chmod 777 /home/docker

USER docker
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 3000
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You may need to check the permissions for your project. It's hard to reproduce that specific issue from that little information.

Comment: I've checked the permission of my project and ran ```chmod 777``` on my project and the error occurs again. I put my dockerfile in here, if have another thing to help you that i can do , please, tell me. Thank you very much for you response.

Comment: I mean more `chown` to see if there's any files owned by `root` that your application needs to operate on. Toby has a good observation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the problem is with the gem `bootsnap` as your error message indicates.

If you look in the [bootsnap documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap) you see this:

> Note that bootsnap writes to tmp/cache, and that directory must be
>   writable. Rails will fail to boot if it is not. If this is
>   unacceptable (e.g. you are running in a read-only container and
>   unwilling to mount in a writable tmpdir), you should remove this line
>   or wrap it in a conditional.

"this line" refers to `require 'bootsnap/setup'` in `config/boot.rb`

So you either need to make sure the tmp/cache directory is writeable in your container or remove the the bootsnap line from `config/boot.rb`